# Laravel Many-to-many relationship three way

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I'm relatively new to Laravel and currently I am facing this problem:

Let's say I have 3 tables:

- `Questionnaires`
- `Questions`
- `Answers`

The relationships for all of them should be many-to-many. So, I have created two pivot tables:

- `questionnaire_question`
- `answer_question`

However, I have to specify one or more correct answers for each question.

Currently, I have set a '`correct`' column in the `answer_question` pivot table to specify if an answer is correct but this approach does not work for my case...

A specific set of answers could be used to **more than one** questionnaires and questions that could possibly have different 'correct answers' in each case.

Thus, I was thinking of having a representation of the correct answers to a table where the `questionnaire_question` id, is associated with many `answers`.

Is this a concept on the correct path and if so, how could this be accomplished?

I have also considered of **Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models** as described on the docs, however I am not sure about how this could be implemented in this case where all relations should be many-to-many.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hello Christopher! I have similar models on my current project. I have `Poll`, `Question` and `Option` models. And also have an `Answer` model to store/access users answer. All of them related "one-to-many". Can you give an real life example for your use case so we can have a clear sight. I didn't quite understand your need actually.

Comment: Consider that if question has different correct answer, is it still same question? Even if two question looks same, are they identical if correct answer is different for each of them? Sometime is is ok to have redundant database to avoid too much complexity.

Comment: @Harven is right. Maybe you are overengineering :) Ok, you have two options with same text but are they really **same** option? If those options are something like `yes` and `no` you are sure to reuse them, you can have a `json` type column as `correct_answers` on your `question` and store correct answers' ids as array in that column. You can check [MySQL JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) available from 5.7

Comment: @UğurArıcı lol JSON columns are not meant to store data like that. If all you're storing is an array in a JSON column than you are likely misusing it as a table

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for responding! Let me clarify the case: @Uğur Arıcı Yes, the answers and even the questions could be exactly the same. For example there are many questions that have as answer options 'Yes/No'. The same applies for the questions too, as there are 5 Questionnaires for 5 different cases that could have some common questions. So when assigning the answers to a question, in the first place, it would be chaotic to select from a list of 20 Yes'. On the other hand a question for a specific questionnaire, could have more than one correct answers.I hope I shed some light! :)

Comment: Hey @Flame I meant if he just needs to check if selected answer is correct for that question on user input, he can be able to control it from that array without need of an another table. I would like to hear your recommendation so I can improve my thoughts :) @ChristopherJones I still think those are different questions and answers. Are you sure those options are `same option`? Or different options with `same text`?

Comment: @Uğur Arıcı Yes, they are the exact same options. And this happens so that the admin does not have to scroll through a huge list of the same options when assigning answer options to a question

Comment: @ChristopherJones So show possible options for an question as static form elements and create new options on database from selected options' texts? In that way every option shows only once (because you writed directly to your form) :) Maybe you don't need to use `exact same` option for all questions but have an `possible options` on database to show admin when he creating a question. In that way you don't hard code the options and store it on your database.

Comment: @Uğur Arıcı Actually nothing is hardcoded. Questions and answers are all stored in the database. The process is as follows: Create a new question -> associate it with a set of answers by selecting them from a list fetched from the database. Or create a new answer so that it can be selected afterwards. This way an answer (i.e 'Yes') can be used to many questions.